# Is it possible to reference a field to a node, and also to a user?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, users

My question: Is it possible to reference a field to a node, and also to a user?

I want to keep track of scores scored by users while playing a boardgame. So, I'll need a reference between nodes (boardgame) and users. I'm using the "entity reference" for this.

With the module field_group and field_group_multiple, I can make rows with user field, score field, etc... But the problem here is: the score field is linked to the node, not to the user. (So if I want to make a view and get all scores scored by a player, this will be not possible.)

Comment: Have you tried the [references] module? (http://drupal.org/project/references)

Comment: who is the author of the boardgame node is it the player or the admin?

Comment: I'm using the entity_reference module to make a reference to all players, so they are not admin's, but that doesn't matter. A boardgame is played with more then one player :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer. The modules entity_reference and field_collection are what I needed. field_collection makes a collection that has a reference to the node, and also to the user_reference. An awesome module!

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT
This would probably be best as a module then.  You could either create separate views of each player or game instance and use view_embed_view() function or  You could use a noad_load() to grab the information as well.

http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load/7

Comment: That's ok for one game and one player, but each boardgame is played with x players. So there has to be a connection between the score, the boardgame AND the player.

Comment: Check out my edit